# my probleme about "The installation or removal of a software package failed"

Tags: apt, package-management

Recently, when I open Ubuntu software center, it ask me repair package

Then I found this message .

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 569135 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.5.0-42-generic (from .../linux-image-3.5.0-42-generic_3.5.0-42.65~precise1_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-42-generic_3.5.0-42.65~precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-42-generic': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.5.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-42-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-42-generic_3.5.0-42.65~precise1_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-quantal:
 linux-image-generic-lts-quantal depends on linux-image-3.5.0-42-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.5.0-42-generic is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-lts-quantal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-quantal:
 linux-generic-lts-quantal depends on linux-image-generic-lts-quantal; however:
  Package linux-image-generic-lts-quantal is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-lts-quantal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `linux-image-3.5.0-42-generic` by running the following command on terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.5.0-42-generic
```

It will solve the problem.